# How to write tests that account for custom User model in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-users, django-unittest

TL;DR:

**I don't wanna use `@skipIfCustomUser`**   What can I do?

---

Django allows a custom user model to be defined in `settings.py`, and says we should use `get_user_model()` to reference the current (swapped) `User` model, [in the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model).

Forthermore, [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/auth/customizing/#custom-users-and-testing-fixtures) are kind to say:

> If you are writing an application that interacts with the User model, you must take some precautions ...
>
> To ensure that your test suite will pass in any project configuration, `django.contrib.auth.tests.utils` defines a `@skipIfCustomUser` decorator. This decorator will cause a test case to be skipped ...

To me it seems reasonable to expect more and more Django projects have a custom user model, and so I'd like to be able to test my app agains these projects too.

But how can I do that?

For reference, here is where it all fails:

```
def setUp(self):
    from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
    User = get_user_model()
    user = User.objects.create_user(
           'test_username', 
           'test_username@example.com', 
           'da_password')  # BAM!
```

That last line will fail if user model does not define a `username` field. That is the case for `CustomUser` example from [Django's own tests](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/auth/customizing/#django.contrib.auth.tests.custom_user.CustomUser).